# LIMIT the user accessebility on a particular table data in DB

Tags: php

I been working on a code, where the user can access the promocode in DB along with discount that comes with it. Now when user has to pay and got a promocode, he enters the same and avails some discount in his pay. 
Now how to limit the promocode access to once?

My code goes as ::

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php

$promocode = $_POST['promocode'];
$payamount = $_POST['payamount'];
$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM apromocode WHERE code = '$promocode' ";
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {                               
while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {

$discount = $row3['discount'];  

$total1 = $discount;
$total2 = $pay - $total1;

$sql = "UPDATE userpaytoget SET payamount = '$total2' 
WHERE mobile = '$mobile'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("PromoCode Applied")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="user-profile.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql3 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Here, i get the payamount and promocode form user while i will check the promocode with the db and get the discount accordingly...

Now here, i dont have any restrictions for user where he can only avail this for once..
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
___We fix your attempts, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a design issue than a code issue. You have to consider whether the rule "promocode can be used only once by a user" applies to every promocode and every user. If yes, then:

- I presume promocode defined in `apromocode` table is already a `UNIQUE KEY` if not `PRIMARY KEY` and that `mobile` is equivalent to certain `user_id` as far as identifying a unique user is concerned.
- In `userpaytoget` table, make a **composite `UNIQUE KEY`** of `mobile` and `code`. This will make sure that a `promocode` can be used by a `mobile` only once.

Now, this will not necessarily ensure that the user gets the error message (since the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operations would simply fail by throwing a `DUPLICATE KEY` error). So, for you to be able to relay that to the user, you could:

- Before inserting or updating a record, check the count of `mobile` and `code`. If it's greater than 0, give your custom error message to the user.

---

A slightly different logic and error handling mechanism will be required if you decide that certain promocodes can be used more than once. In that case,

- You could add a new column, say, `max_usage_count` in `apromocode`.
- This will also mean that **Composite `UNIQUE KEY`** defined in `userpaytoget` will have to be removed. However, you could still check the `COUNT` of `mobile` and `promocode` before `INSERT` / `UPDATE`, compare it with the `max_usage_count` and accordingly decide whether or not to allow the operation.

Hope that helps.